# Oracle Apex 5.0: Can you use the action menu buttons on an Interactive report when the action bar is set to not show?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In Apex 5.0 working with Interactive reports I am able to take the functionality from the action menu buttons and use them in a button. The code I use is:

```
javascript:$("#CloseoutReport_actions_menu").menu("find","irDownload").action()
```

The CloseoutReport is the static Id of my interactive report and the action i chose to use is the Download function. Now this works when I have the action menu set to show, but when I hide the action menu, this no longer works. Is it a possibility to do what I am trying when I hide the action bar? I just want to show a single button with the download option.  Thanks for any comments or answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more solutions to your problem but the most easy one i think is to add `display:none` to the class of the action bar.

Like this:

```
.a-IRR-toolbar  {
    display: none;
}
```

The difference between setting the item to `display: none` and setting the action bar to not show is that in the second case the database does not send any javascript of the action bar to your browser so you can not use its functionalities but in the first case you get all the functionalities but you hide them.

Comment: I put the code in my page inline css, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a simple download button? In this case you can simply create a button with request `IR[CloseoutReport]_CSV`.

Example for manual link: `https://foo.bar:1234/pls/apex/f?p=100:2:123456:IR[CloseoutReport]_CSV`.

Comment: I am using more than just the download, I am using most of the action menu functionality